# When I use the Plancherel Theorem I get that $\pi = \frac{1}{2} $ What's wrong?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

From the Plancherel theorem I know that:  $2\pi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)g(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frak{F}(f)\frak{F}(g) d\xi $

I need to prove the equality below by using the Plancherel theorem :

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{ab}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)} dx = \frac{\pi}{a+b}     $ with a, b > 0

What I did :

Let $f(x) = \frac{a}{x^2 +a^2}$ and  $g(x) = \frac{b}{x^2 +b^2}    $

$\frak{}F(f) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$e^{-a|\xi|} $

$\frak{}F^{-1}(g) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$e^{-b|\xi|} $

And now, using the Pancherel theorem, can I say that the following is correct?

$2\pi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{ab}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}  dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$e^{-a|\xi|} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$e^{-b|\xi|}   d\xi  = \frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{(-a-b)|\xi|} d\xi $

if it is correct, then i get the right answer.

What troubles my mind is that it implies that:

$2\pi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{ab}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}  dx = \frac{\pi}{a+b}  = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{ab}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)} dx$

then it gets insane and:

$2\pi  \frac{\pi}{a+b}  = \frac{\pi}{a+b} $

therefore:
$\pi  = \frac{1}{2} $

Why do i get $\frac{\pi}{a+b}$ calculating the right side integral from the Plancherel Theorem but it still looks like it isn't the right answer?

Comment: Do you notice anything different about Plancharels formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem) to what you have written above? Maybe [this will help](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/~fionn/teaching/archive/1314/ma22s3/plancharel.pdf).

Comment: You have some factors of $\sqrt{2\pi}$ that you need to examine more carefully.